# How to "extern" a function in multiple modules with the same name?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I have a lib project with multiple modules called `one` and `two`, in separate files. Each module has a function called `run`:

```
mod one {
    pub fn run() {
        println!("One");
    }
}

mod two {
    pub fn run() {
        println!("Two");
    }
}

fn main() {
    one::run();
    two::run();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67393a8b07045579d8de0ffb59a2d2dd)

I would like to compile each of these files/functions to WebAssembly and then be able to load them and call the function `run()`.

I believe I have to add the `#[no_mangle]` directive and mark them as `extern "C"` functions. When I do that, then there is a name clash on the `run` function, despite the module structure.

This is the modified version that won't compile:

```
mod one {
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn run() {
        println!("One");
    }
}

mod two {
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn run() {
        println!("Two");
    }
}

fn main() {
    one::run();
    two::run();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69c6f77605709af52d3eda7257285c3b)

Is there a way to have multiple modules in a project, each with a function with the same name, such that I can compile the files with the function to WebAssembly, preserving the function name?

Comment: But then when you call `run` from the web assembly, which function should get called?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you know about `wasm-bindgen`? That seems to be the de-facto solution for WASM stuff right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot give multiple things the same name in a global namespace. That's kind of the definition of what a name and a namespace is. You will need to export them as two different names.

I prefer to have a single location that exports things so it's easier to see and prevent clashes. Additionally, your symbols should be unique among **all** libraries that will ever be linked with your library. That's why most high-quality C projects use the library name in every single public method.

```
mod one {
    pub fn run() {
        println!("One");
    }
}

mod two {
    pub fn run() {
        println!("Two");
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn mylib_one_run() {
    one::run()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn mylib_two_run() {
    two::run()
}

fn main() {
    one::run();
    two::run();
}
```

See also:

- [How do I apply a macro attribute to a function defined in a separate module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364002/155423)

Comment: Thanks. Just to be 100% clear. It's the "extern" keyword that effectively takes the fn name from within a module and makes it available in the global namespace?

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie no, it's `no_mangle`: "do not mangle this function name so that it's (very likely to be) unique in the global namespace, I will handle it."